# dual transform of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X,Y$ be two vector spaces with algebraic duals $X^* ,Y^*$ respectively. Consider a linear transformation $T: X \to Y$. The dual $T^*$ of $T$ is defined to be the linear transformation $T^* : Y^* \to X^*$ such that 
$$ T^* (\phi)(v) = \phi (T(v) ) $$
holds for all $v \in X, \phi \in Y^* $.

We can easily see that the mapping $T \mapsto T^*$ is injective from the space of linear transformations from $X$ to $Y$ to the space of linear transfomrations from $Y^*$ to $X^*$. In the wikipedia page

```
             https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map
```

It says that the above mapping $T \mapsto T^*$ is surjective, and hence an isomorhpism, if and only if $Y$ is finite-dimensional.

I can see the 'if' part, but I cannot see the 'only if' part. What is the example of a linear transform $F : Y^* \to X^* $ such that there is no $G : X \to Y$ with $G^* = F$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Take any infinite dimensional $K$-vector space $Y$. Then the natural map $Y\rightarrow Y^{**}$ is injective, but not surjective. Let $X =K$. Then $\hom_K(K,Y) = Y$ and $\hom_K(Y^*,K) = Y^{**}$, i. e. the map
$$
\hom_K(K,Y) = Y\longrightarrow Y^{**} = \hom_K(Y^*,K),\qquad T\longmapsto T^*
$$
is injective but not surjective.

Comment: Note that we can't actually name any of the elements in $V^{**}$ that aren't in the image of $V\rightarrow V^{**}$, because the proof of injectivity relies on the axiom of choice.